# Show jsp page inside jar file using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, war

I'm developing a web application in java using Spring MVC 3.2.2. I'm having problems loading jsp page from within the jar file.

The Sring MVC web application that the following structure:

```
|-META-INF
|-WEB-INF
    |-spring
    |    |- app-config.xml
    |-classes
    |-lib
    |   |-external.jar
    |       |-WEB-INF
    |       |   |-views
    |       |       |-external.jsp
    |       |-classes
    |            |-controller-for-external.class
    |-views
        |-... jsp
```

Config in app-config.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/views/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Controller for external.jsp

```
   @Controller
    public class ExternalController {
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value="/external.htm")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("msg", "External page loaded");
    return new ModelAndView("external", "model", myModel);
}
```

}

web.xml file

```
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Springapp</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When a try to show external.jsp page, spring don't want search it and show error HTTP 404 - /springapp/WEB-INF/views/external.jsp

Answer (score 20):

You can do this if you are using Servlet 3.0. However, it won't work with the way you have your JSPs packaged. You have to package resources into a JAR file in a specific way:

- Put all your JSPs in the `META-INF/resources` directory of your JAR.
- Include a `web-fragment.xml` file in `META-INF`. This is similar to a typical `web.xml` with some differences. See [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) for some details. There is also an example I found [here](https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/impl-servlet/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml). This is optional.
- Put your JAR in `WEB-INF/lib` of your WAR.

Now you should be able to refer to those JSPs within your app's context. Basically `META-INF/resources` is mapped to the document root of your webapp. Look at [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/web_inf_lib_jar_meta) for more details. Keep in mind that this is not limited to JSPs. You can put images, JavaScript, or even CSS in there.

Comment: This works perfectly and should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks Vivin for your solution. It worked for me.

In my case, I had:

**testModule.jar**

```
    test/
        TestModule.class
    META-INF/
        resources/
            WEB-INF/
                views/
                    testModule.jsp
        MANIFEST.MF
        web-fragment.xml (empty)
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
```

**testProject.war**

```
    test/
        ...
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF/
        spring/
            ... spring configs ...
        views/
            test.jsp
        lib/
            testModule.jar
        web.xml
```

It may be important to say that Servlet 3.0 **do not handle fragments on an Eclipse deployment  scenario** in Glassfish 3.1.2 (it maybe works in JBoss or others, to be confirmed). Actually, I set testModule.jar in deployment assembly of testProject.war and when I deploy through Eclipse, it generates a folder testModule.jar instead of a JAR file.

But it's working when exporting as a WAR.

**EDIT:**

To get it working with Eclipse deployment, you have to check an option in Glassfish 3.1.2 properties : Deploy as jar. I think it's a recent option implemented in the last plugin version. Visible on Kepler but not on Juno.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the working structure. It really help me.

Comment: Did you work with Spring MVC? Can you provide me ViewResolver bean config follow this structure?

Answer (score 2):

I did it using Vivin's solution. Here's the folder structure of my JAR in Eclipse.

[image]

Included the jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my WAR:

[image]

Also added the following in my pom.xml of WAR:

```
 <configuration><packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingIncludes>
 </configuration>
```

Included the jsp in my Web Project using :

```
<jsp:include page="/myService.jsp" flush="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure works for me

**jar module (jar)**
[image]

**main web app module (war)**
[image]

And ViewResolver config (I'm using Thymeleaf):

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/template/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
```